# XPath Query to select hyperlink

Tags: xpath

The following is a subset of xml from a twitter atom feed:

```
<entry>
    <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:18232030105964545</id>
    <published>2010-12-24T09:10:29Z</published>
    <link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="http://twitter.com/KTNKenya/statuses/18232030105964545"/>
    <title>Synovate Poll: PM Raila Odinga remains the preffered presidential candidate at 42% while Uhuru Kenyatta is at 14%... http://fb.me/yjmMbmBx</title>
    <content type="html">Synovate Poll: PM &lt;b&gt;Raila&lt;/b&gt; Odinga remains the preffered presidential candidate at 42% while Uhuru Kenyatta is at 14%... &lt;a href=&quot;http://fb.me/yjmMbmBx&quot;&gt;http://fb.me/yjmMbmBx&lt;/a&gt;</content>
    <updated>2010-12-24T09:10:29Z</updated>
    <link type="image/png" rel="image" href="http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/701825859/NEW_KTN_normal.png"/>
    <google:location>nairobi, kenya</google:location>
    <twitter:geo>
    </twitter:geo>
    <twitter:metadata>
        <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
    </twitter:metadata>
    <twitter:source>&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.facebook.com/twitter&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Facebook&lt;/a&gt;</twitter:source>
    <twitter:lang>en</twitter:lang>
    <author>
        <name>KTNKenya (KTN Kenya)</name>
        <uri>http://twitter.com/KTNKenya</uri>
    </author>
</entry>
```

From the `<title>...</title>` element, i need to select the hyperlink *http://fb.me/yjmMbmBx* via an XPath query. How do I do it? Is it possible? 
*I'm an XPath newbie.

Thanks.

Comment: @lzmoto: You can **select** the text node containing that kind of string value. You also can get that string, but only for one `entry` only in XPath 1.0

Comment: @Alejandro: Thank you for quick response. Please provide me with a sample XPath query. Thanks

Comment: I'm sure someone will do it. But first you need to clarify if you want all the `title`'s text nodes containing some URI or the URI contained in **one** `tiltle` and wich one.

Comment: @Alejandro: To clarify, I want all the <title>...</title> text nodes containing some URI. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use <title> (xpath: "/entry/title/text()") and get the URL yourself (e.g. using regex or finding the last instance of "http://" in the string.
2. Get the  data first:

   ```
   /entry/content[@type="html"]/text()
   ```

   Then you need to parse this as HTML and extract any  tags, and use the href attribute of those tags. How you do this last part depends on the language/environment you are doing this in.

**Update:** Added basic example code for option 1 above, as requested:

```
xmlpp::Element *node = parser.get_document()->get_root_node();
xmlpp::NodeSet results = node->find("/entry/title/text()"); 
xmlpp::ContentNode* content = dynamic_cast<xmlpp::ContentNode*>(results.front());
std::string text = content->get_content();
std::string link = "";
int res = text.rfind("http://");
if(res == text.npos)
    res = text.rfind("https://");
if(res != text.npos)
    link = text.substr(res);
```

Comment: I'm using c++ (libxml with Samsung Bada) - option 1 is great, could you provide an example? Thanks much.

Comment: I've added some example code, it lacks any error checking, and assumes you only want http(s) URLs. It doesn't check the URL validity, etc. but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

With `atom` prefix bound to `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace URI, use:

```
/atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:title[contains(.,'http://')]
```

This selects every `atom:title` element child of `atom:entry`, having the string "http://" contained in its string value.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thank you. I am almost there now :-) Now I need to modify the query to only get me any URI only and not the entire text. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: @Izmoto: You wrote: *Now I need to modify the query to only get me any URI only and not the entire text*. That's wrong, and that's why I was asking to clarify the question. In XPath 1.0 you can selects every `title` or `title`'s text node containing some URI, or **one** string equal to such URI.

Comment: @Alejandro: Now I understand your explanation. So how do I go about selecting only the URI if any is found? Thanks

Comment: @Izmoto: You should do that in the host language with any string manipulation method.

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks so much for your input - you've helped me greatly :-)